# Deploy app to phone over network

Tags: ios, networking, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm developing an iOS app on a virtual machine, so I am not able to use a USB cable to install my app on an iOS device.  Is it possible to deploy the app to my device over the network?

Thanks

Comment: If you can't even get a cert to the device, deploying a binary will make your life a living hell.  See [here](http://krish.codeworth.com/development/iphone-2/how-to-create-a-ad-hoc-build-in-xcode-for-testing-ios-app/) for an example though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  The TestFlight option fits my needs better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com)